# show last searched items below search form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a search form which is developed using redux form. I have used router to route to the form. After i submit the data from search form and revert back to the same form, i want to show a list of data that had been searched before whenever user clicks on search places input box. How can i do so?

Like in the image

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
const Banner = (props) => (
  <Router>
    <div className="container banner">
      <ServiceType />
          <div className="row">
            <Match exactly pattern="/" location={props.location} component={Apartamentos} />
            <Match pattern="/apartamentos" component={Apartamentos} />
            <Match pattern="/coche" component={Coche} />
            <Match pattern="/experiencias" component={Experiencias} />
          </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
);


const renderGeoSuggestField = ({
  input,
  location
}) => (
  <Geosuggest
    fixtures={fixtures}
    initialValue={input.value.label}
    inputClassName="form-control destino"
    onChange={(value) => input.onChange(value)}
    onSuggestSelect={(value) => input.onChange(value)}
    radius="20"
  />
);

const renderDateRangePicker = ({
  input,
  focusedInput,
  onFocusChange,
}) => (
  <DateRangePicker
    onDatesChange={(start, end) => input.onChange(start, end)}
    startDate={(input.value && input.value.startDate) || null}
    endDate={(input.value && input.value.endDate) || null}
    minimumNights={0}
  />
);

class ServiceType extends Component {
render() {
  return(
    div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 serviceImg">
      <Link to="/apartamentos">
        <img
          src={imageUrl}
          alt="apartamentos"
          className="img-responsive"
        />
        <h4>APARTAMENTOS</h4>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
}


class Apartamentos extends Component {
  render() {
    const { focusedInput } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="form-box text-center">
        <div className="container">
          <form className="form-inline">
            <div className="form-group">
              <Field
                name='geoSuggest'
                component={renderGeoSuggestField}
                onChange={(value) => this.onChange(value)}
                onSuggestSelect={(suggest) => this.onSuggestSelect(suggest)}
                location={new google.maps.LatLng(53.558572, 9.9278215)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <Field
                name="daterange"
                onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
                focusedInput={focusedInput}
                component={renderDateRangePicker}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <Field
                name="persona"
                component="select"
              >
                <option>1 persona</option>
                <option>2 personas</option>
              </Field>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default buscar">BUSCAR</button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ApartmentForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'ApartmentForm',
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
})(Apartamentos);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is maintain is a `redux` state variable called say `previousSearches` which is initialized as an empty array. Everytime you click `Submit` push the form data into this `previousSearches` array. So when you click on the input button next just display all information from the `previousSearches` array (which is a `redux` variable and can be accessed as a `prop`).

Something like this I guess

```
case 'ADD_PREVIOUS_SEARCH':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                previousSearches: state.previousSearches.push(action.search)
            })
```

Then you can just access `previousSearches` by `this.props.previousSearches`

Comment: That means i should dispatch onSubmit action and create a reducer which stores the pushed form data, right?

Comment: Yes. You can send the form data as an `action` argument and push it in the array in the `reducer`.

Modified the answer.